# MySQL Where first character equals to

Tags: mysql

So I have a table which contains `Initials` (e.g CF, AB, F, G). I'm trying to do an `UPDATE` query `WHERE Initials<first character> = something`. (e.g `Initials[0] = "C"`). How can I do this in MySQL? I checked a few solutions but they seem overly complex. Is there a simple way to do this?

Example Table:

**Initials**

```
Initial | Last_Name | Approved
CF      | Smith     | Yes
AD      | Jones     |
B       | Reed      |
```

I'm trying to UPDATE the table above, and check if the `Last_name` and First Character of the `Initial` match, then set `Approved` to `Yes`.

So, for example: `UPDATE Initials SET Approved = 'YES' WHERE Last_Name = 'Jones' AND Initial[0] = 'A'`

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: what do you mean by "match"?  why should Jones be A, not B or C?

Answer (score 1):

You could use left() function

```
Update  my_table  
set  your_col = 'your_value'
where left( your_initial_col,1)  ='C'
```

in your case should  be

```
Update  my_table  
set  SET Approved = 'YES' 
where lats_name like concat(left( initial,1) , '%')
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks! I actually updated my original question, but you got it spot on.

Comment: answer  updated .. hope is waht you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

you can try this query:

```
UPDATE <table_name> SET <columne_name>='<new value>' WHERE Initial LIKE 'C%'
```

or in case of multible columns:

```
UPDATE <table_name> 
 SET <columne_name_1>='<new value_1>', <columne_name_2>='<new value_2>'
WHERE Initial LIKE 'C%'
```

it should work;

Comment: %STARTSWITH appears to be an IRIS operator, not one supported in MySQL

Comment: @ysth you're right (y), i have modified my answer; thanks